# How to use GetChanges API for File Folder changes in MS Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have added some folder and files to 'Shared Documents' and trying to read get changes response.
Please have a look at my /getchanges request and response below:

```
POST https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getchanges?$filter=(Time ge datetime'2018-04-03T09:24:17Z')

{"query":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.ChangeQuery"},"Add":true,"Web":true,"Site":true,"Update": true, "DeleteObject":true, "File":true, "Folder":true, "ContentType":true}}
```

For the above request I am getting below response:

```
{  
   [
            "odata.type": "SP.ChangeFile",
            "odata.id": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.ChangeFile7f33e785-a5dc-424a-bc31-d953171db7b2",
            "odata.editLink": "SP.ChangeFile7f33e785-a5dc-424a-bc31-d953171db7b2",
            "ChangeToken": {
                "StringValue": "1;2;155cd6ac-2fa5-4fc6-8297-10917724fcdf;636583446482830000;79145543"
            },
            "ChangeType": 1,
            "SiteId": "f6aea202-e4c9-4a16-927d-a222975c592e",
            "Time": "2018-04-03T09:30:48Z",
            "UniqueId": "83746e80-56e7-4b76-9427-6920b0677447",
            "WebId": "155cd6ac-2fa5-4fc6-8297-10917724fcdf"
        },
        {
            "odata.type": "SP.ChangeFolder",
            "odata.id": "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.ChangeFolder202b82c0-4a3a-4b70-879a-8d41b63ced7f",
            "odata.editLink": "SP.ChangeFolder202b82c0-4a3a-4b70-879a-8d41b63ced7f",
            "ChangeToken": {
                "StringValue": "1;2;155cd6ac-2fa5-4fc6-8297-10917724fcdf;636583446489070000;79145549"
            },
            "ChangeType": 2,
            "SiteId": "f6aea202-e4c9-4a16-927d-a222975c592e",
            "Time": "2018-04-03T09:30:49Z",
            "UniqueId": "6847b1e9-169b-4d15-9c3c-0b3b1a9848a8",
            "WebId": "155cd6ac-2fa5-4fc6-8297-10917724fcdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am facing below issues for getchanges api:

1. getchanges API not returning changes in response in case of File and Folder. It is returning file and folders updated yesterday. 
   Same API worked perfectly fine with List, ListItem, etc.
2. For above response, how can I retrieve which folder or file was added/updated, as I am getting webid and siteid in response

Please suggest?